# Blue Marble rasters and NaturalEarth shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, natural-earth

I am working on a personal 3D project which combines metadata from shapefiles, and rasters for topography, true color, bathymetry, etc...

I am using the Blue marble images (which I understand are using the WSG Datum WGS84 and the Plate Carrée projection) with shapefiles from natural-earth (which also use the WSG Datum WGS84).

It was my understanding that both are using the same projection (which could be referenced with epsg:4326) and indeed they seem to match to a point.

However when looking at lands near the the poles, some inconsistencies are very apparent (see screenshot of Greenland below)

[image: Blue Marble + Natural Earth Coastlines]

Looking at the Blue Marble Navigator (blue-marble.de) which offers an interface to navigate through the Blue Marble images, I noticed the exact same discrepancy (see screenshot below, with the mismatched black zones)

[image: Blue Marble Navigator Screenshot: Greenland]

Should I re-project the raster/shapefiles with a different projection, or are the Blue Marble images altogether unfit to be correctly matched to epsg:4326 shapefiles?

Answer (score 3):

This could very well be an issue with when the imagery was taken. Along the coast, high vs low tide can greatly affect the imagery collection.

[NOAA Tidal Facts](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/highesttide.html) talks about some of the greater differences between high and low tide:

> The highest tides in the world can be found in Canada at the Bay of
>   Fundy, which separates New Brunswick from Nova Scotia. At some times
>   of the year the difference between high and low tide in this Bay is
>   16.3 meters, taller than a three-story building.
>
> The highest tides in the United States can be found near Anchorage,
>   Alaska, with tidal ranges up to 12.2 meters.

A 10 meter or so difference would definitely show some low lying land during low tide that wouldn't be detected in imagery taken during high.